# Laravel TicketIt routing issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, ticket-system

I am using [TicketIt](https://github.com/thekordy/ticketit) for my Laravel 5.2 ticket system.

I've installed it and everything works fine however the current route for the ticket homepage is set to `/tickets`.

I want my Laravel app to automatically redirect to `/tickets` on the homepage. So whenever `/` is requested it should redirect to `/tickets`.

As all of the source code for TicketIt is stored in `/vendor/kordy/ticketit/src` so I'm not sure how to do this. Any ideas?

My routes file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});


Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Comment: Do you first have access to `/tickets`/ ? Does it display anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple redirect on the homepage to `/tickets`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/tickets');
});
```